# Connect to remote database from Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, ssh, homestead

I am trying to connect my Homestead Laravel project to a remote db hosted on Fasthosts but I get the error ;
`ssh: connect to host 213.xxx.xxx.xx port 22: Connection timed out`

I have tried this in my homestead

```
ssh -fNg -L 3333:localhost:3306 user@213.xxx.xxx.xx
```

This is my .env db settings

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=213.xxx.xxx.xx
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=dbname
 DB_USERNAME=user
 DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

I am not sure why the connection to the remote database is timing out. Any ideas to help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: It cannot connect to port 22 on the server 213.xx.xx.xx. If that is not your server, you'll need to contact the hosting server. If it is your server, check the firewall and if the service is working on that port.

Comment: @aynber it is a shared host package i have with Fasthost and not really a VPS.

Comment: Then you definitely need to contact Fasthost to verify that port 22 is open and listening. Or try just `ssh user@213.xxx.xxx.xx` without any other commands to see if that works. Then you know where you can start narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @aynber after contacting fasthost support it was discovered that I hadn't given DBO access to the user i created. The little things does drive you crazy atimes.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if your databse stack is bitnami there is a process to open port, and if your stack is on AWS and is bitnami stack you must open ports in the cloud platform of amazon